# How to make a ip address assigned printer non-discoverable using the printer settings

Tags: networking, printing, printer

okay, I have static IP addressed networked printers, not on a print server but standalones. I would like to have these printers non-discoverable by all on the network, but I would also like them to be added to induvial computers as needed using there respective IP addresses. Can this be done and what are the steps if possible, thinking there must be a setting on the printer it's self to make this work as there are no network settings I can do to prevent this that I know of without a print server handling them.
All OS's are either Windows 10Pro or 11Pro

Comment: If you want to know what settings a printer might have, you'd obviously need to write which printer that is. Also, it might be doable to block connections from certain devices to certain devices in better routers, so also write which networking router you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferred: Put the printer in a separate network subnet (e.g. a separate VLAN) from the computers. Most discovery protocols will not cross a router into a different subnet (and if they do, the router's firewall can be easily configured to block them), while directed connections will go through subnets without any problems.

If you don't want a separate subnet: Search the printer's settings for "mDNS", "DNS-SD", "Bonjour", "AirPrint", or "WS-Discovery". Disable those features if found. Those are the most common printer discovery protocols used these days (WS-Discovery is the Windows specific one, while mDNS/Bonjour/DNS-SD is Apple; all of the other names refer roughly to the same thing).